# Asynchronous file transfer in ASP.Net Chat Application (peer to peer)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, wcf, file

I've developed a chat application using WCF/ASp.net. I want to asynchronously transfer a file from one chat user to another chat user. What is best approach for this?

here are my insights/doubts

1. Do i need a central server between
   two users to assist the file
   transfer?
2. Can i create a direct channel
   without a central server?
3. Do i need to store/upload it
   anywhere for file transfer?
4. How should i make the file transfer
   reliable?

Comment: can you use a third party plugin like Silverlight or does this have to be a native-browser experience?

Comment: Its better to have it as a 'native-browser experience' as you define using Ajax/JQuery/WCF/Asp.Net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it is virtually impossible to do the file transfer by establishing a channel between the two clients directly without a server. So a central server should exist to server the file transfer. I also i found that WCF offers excellent support for file transfer in terms of different bindings and chunking-mechanism.